# Google Chart Bar Blue to White

Tags: javascript

I' am using Google Chart. I was searching on Google and found some API options to set in to get the color of the bar from default blue to white. This is what I have added into the option parameters:

Someone said that this will only work if you want more then one color of bars

```
colors: '#FFF'
```

This is also what I tried. Saw this somewhere so thought to apply it.

```
color: '#FFF'
```

For some reason its not working as wanted. Here's my javascript code in placed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'Current Demand'],
          <?php echo $data; ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
                width: 350,
                height: 261,
                isStacked: true,
                legend: 'none',
                backgroundColor: { 
                        fill:'transparent' 
                    },
                hAxis: {
                        title: '', 
                        titleTextStyle: {color: 'white'
                    },
                colors: '#FFF'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors need to be put into a javascript array.

```
colors: ['#fff']
```

Comment: oh oh thanks. I want putting the color in wrong place. thanks man!